# Getting the file handles of given process

Tags: c#, winapi

I need a way for getting all of the file handles of a given process.

for example, given a the winword.exe process handle, i would like to get the list of the file handles of that process (doc files etc).

i'm using the Win32 api via C#/pInvoke.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use [handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) and read its output. Another solution is to use P/Invoke with [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509(VS.85).aspx) function. [This](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic14546.html) and [this](http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html) forum post on SysInternals has more details as well as this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170) on CodeProject. Doing it in managed code could be very difficult as you will need to write a driver to read the kernel address space.

I would suggest you to expose the needed functionality in a Win32 function that you could call from managed code.

Comment: can handle.exe view STDERR and STDOUT? when I do `handle.exe -a -p 1234`, the lowest handle number outputted is 4, but STDERR is #2 correct?

Answer (score 0):

In complement to Darin answer, see also [this codeguru page](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/system/processesmodules/article.php/c2827/) and [this sysinternal forum post](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=3577)